# Change Google Analytics code using Plates

Tags: node.js, flatiron.js, plates

Is there a way to change the Google Analytics code included in a template using Plates?

For example, for the below template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script id="googleAnalytics">
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','GA_ACCOUNT_CODE'],['_trackPageview']];
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to use a different `GA_ACCOUNT_CODE` depending on the environment the code runs in.

Is this possible with Plates? If not, what is the common way one would solve this issue in NodeJS & Flatiron?

Comment: What is "Plates" in this context?

Comment: I've updated the tag wiki, for now: Light-weight, logic-less, DSL-free, templates for all javascript environments; https://github.com/flatiron/plates

Answer (score 0):

Plates' idea is great but far from complete. Here is a solution.

### app.js

var fs       = require('fs');
    var plates   = require('plates');
    var flatiron = require('flatiron');
    var app      = flatiron.app;

```
app.use(flatiron.plugins.http);

app.router.get('/', function(){
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8');
    var map  = plates.Map();
    var data = {"GA_ACCOUNT_CODE": "YOUR_CODE_FROM_CONFIG"}

    map.where('data-ga').is('GA_ACCOUNT_CODE').insert('GA_ACCOUNT_CODE');
    html = plates.bind(html, data, map);
    this.res.html(html);
});

app.start(3000);
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script id="googleAnalytics" data-ga="GA_ACCOUNT_CODE">
            var GA_ACCOUNT_CODE = document.getElementById('googleAnalytics').getAttribute('data-ga');

            var _gaq=[['_setAccount',GA_ACCOUNT_CODE],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another way would just be string.replace() like this:

```
var html = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8');
html     = html.replace('GA_ACCOUNT_CODE', 'YOUR_CODE_FROM_CONFIG');

this.res.html(html);
```

Have a look at [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) for support. It's like any other css selector and dom manipulation frontend library, just backends.